# Adding operator into a string (R)

Tags: r, string

for a plot in R, I am using `facet_wrap` and I want to change the labeling of each facet using a function to give to "labeller". Since one of my facet tiles should be a string of this type: V_>1 (with ">1" as a subscript of V), I have used this `"V[>1]"` but it generates an error:

`Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : <text>:1:3: unexpected '>'1: V[>`

I have also tried with "V[>1]", but this doesn't work too.
Can you give me any suggestions?

---

As an example, we can use the iris dataframe and try to rename the facets:

```
my_labeller <- as_labeller(c(setosa="A[0]", versicolor="B^1", virginica="Gamma"),default = label_parsed)
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  facet_wrap(~Species, labeller = my_labeller)
```

which produces this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/djhcT.png

However, if I try to include a ">" in the text, like this,

```
my_labeller <- as_labeller(c(setosa="A[>0]", versicolor="B[1]", virginica="Gamma"),default = label_parsed)
ggplot(iris) +
      geom_bar(aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
      facet_wrap(~Species, labeller = my_labeller)
```

it does not work:

````
Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : <text>:1:3: unexpected '>'
1: A[> ```
````

Comment: Does `expression("V"[">1"])` work in your context?

Comment: il seems in this way that it does not use the labeller option, because it does change the facet titles

Comment: @Betty Please note that you've accepted an answer that was posted **after** my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_labeller <- as_labeller(c(setosa = "A['>0']",
                             versicolor = "B[1]",
                             virginica = "Gamma"),
                           default = label_parsed)
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @Jose could you in all honesty let OP know that your answer was posted later than my answer?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann: yes indeed, my answer came after yours. I'm sorry about that: I really didn't see your post before posting mine and it was quite similar. I have no problem about Betty accepting your answer instead of mine. Please let me know if I can do anything about that

Comment: Let's wait how @Betty decides. But thank you very much for your candor! It is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_labeller <- as_labeller(c(setosa="A['>'][0]", 
                             versicolor="B^1", 
                             virginica="Gamma"), default = label_parsed)
```

[image]